# how can i cancel editing in CListCtrl by hitting the "cancel" key?

Tags: c++, listview, mfc, listbox, clistctrl

I'm editing an item in CListCtrl control. an edit box appears where I can enter text.
The event of entering the text will, however, not be catched by the LVN_KEYDOWN handler.
how do I catch it otherwise? any samples?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting ESC does cancels editing the label of CListCtrl so what is the "**Cancel**" key exactly?

Comment: you're right of course, the behaviour was because of my own code.